# Jenkins execute Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try to find out, wheter it's possible to trigger a pipeline from a Freestyle-Project. Also I want to to hand over a paramter (revision-number) to the pipeline when I trigger it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure, you should just add to freestyle job name of your pipeline and set needed parameters.

[image]

And, please, don't worry if this job will be unresolved, on freestyle job view, everything will work correct.

Comment: yes, sure. if your pipeline have parameters, on predefined section you should define parameters for example - on pipeline you have one param - BUILD_VERSION and on root job you have this parameter too, you set on predefined section next line BUILD_VERSION=${BUILD_VERSION}, this parameter will be set on your pipeline job.